# Python exec NameError

Tags: python, scope

I have a string variable containing a function. the function looks like this:

```
def program():
    x[0] = y[1]
    z[0] = x[0]
    out = z[0]
```

This is within a method:

```
def runExec(self, stringCode):
    x = [1,2,3,4]
    y = [5,6,7,8]
    z = [6,7,8,9]
    exec stringCode
    return out
```

I am receiving a NameError, it seems x, y and z are not accessible from the stringCode exec ?

How can I make these variables accessible, do I have to pass them in some way ?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to use `exec`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Assuming you have a good reason to use `exec`**, which is an assumption you should double-check.*

You need to supply the global and local scope for the `exec` function.  Also, the "program" string needs to actually run instead of just defining a function.  This will work:

```
prog = """
x[0] = y[1]
z[0] = x[0]
out = z[0]
"""

def runExec(stringCode):
    x = [1,2,3,4]
    y = [5,6,7,8]
    z = [6,7,8,9]
    exec(stringCode, globals(), locals())
    return out

print runExec(prog)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to use `exec`? The following code should work the same way, just without `exec`:

```
def program(x, y, z):
    x[0] = y[1]
    z[0] = x[0]
    out = z[0]
    return out

def runExec(self, func):
    x = [1,2,3,4]
    y = [5,6,7,8]
    z = [6,7,8,9]
    out = func(x, y, z)
    return out

self.runExec(program)
```

Comment: I need to use exec, it's not going to be the same code every time the code is being generated on the fly. The above is just an example.

Answer (score 1):

You can make them global.

```
global x,y,z
def runExec(self, func):
    x = [1,2,3,4]
    y = [5,6,7,8]
    z = [6,7,8,9]
    out = func(x, y, z)
    return out
```